# Getting user input and chopping it up into a struct to be passe back for execvp

Tags: c, linux

So what I am trying to do essentially is get user input. The user types a command maybe something like `command arg1 arg2 arg3`. So I made a struct to hold the base command `command` and an arguments pointer to a pointer of a char to hold the argument `arg1 arg2 arg3` as well as a count to hold the arg count.

In main I get user input with fgets which I then take in and pass to my splitCommand function. The splitCommand function takes the char* which is the full command with args. It then uses strtok to chop it up and stores it into a struct, passing the struct back to main.

The problem I have is that when i run it, and if i type `command arg1 arg2` it prints out `command arg1 (null)`. So I can't tell if I am just confused and referencing the arguments part of the struct wrong, or if I am not copying the arguments properly into the struct.

Any help or point in the right direction as to what I am doing wrong would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advanced.

```
struct Command
{
  char *base;
  char **arguments; //array of pointers
  int count;
};

//Takes a commands string and splits by spaces, returning a string array, including command
struct Command splitCommand(char *cmd)
{
  char *cmdArgs[MAXARGS];

  char *cmd_token = strtok(cmd, " "); //set pointer to first space
  cmd_token = strtok(NULL, " ");      //Chop off first command
  char *cmdFirst = strtok(cmd, " ");  //First command
  int totalArgs = 0;                  //argument counter
  struct Command retCommand;          //command struct
  retCommand.base = cmdFirst;

  //Loop through and get all args
  for (int i = 0; i < MAXARGS; i++)
  {
    if (cmd_token != NULL)
    {
      totalArgs++;
      cmdArgs[i] = cmd_token;
      cmd_token = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }
  }

  retCommand.arguments = cmdArgs;
  retCommand.count = totalArgs;
  return retCommand;
}

//MAIN
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
  //String Array and memory allocation
  char *userCommands[MAXCMDS];
  for (int i = 0; i < MAXCMDS; i++)
  {
    userCommands[i] = malloc(MAXIN);
  }

  //Command 1
  printf("Welcome to MASH!\nmash-1>");
  fgets(userCommands[0], MAXIN, stdin);
  struct Command cmd1 = splitCommand(userCommands[0]);
  printf("%s ", cmd1.base);
  printf("%s ", cmd1.arguments[0]);
  printf("%s ", cmd1.arguments[1]);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: The `splitCommand` function should not returns the local variable `retCommand` since the memory allocated for it is freed at the end of the function. You have to `malloc` it to be allowed to return it.

Comment: @JoëlHecht There's nothing wrong with returning (the value of) local variables.

Comment: `retCommand.arguments` points to the local array `cmdArgs` which ceases to exist when `splitCommand` exits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `strtok` in an unintended manner. You must call it exactly once with `cmdString` for its first parameter to get the first token, then all successive calls with `NULL` to get the rest.

Additionally, your code does not compile. When posting to SO, you should always provide code that at least compiles with no errors.

Here is your code hacked up to work as (I think) you intended.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXARGS 256
#define MAXIN 4096

struct Command {
  char *cmdLine; // copy of command line; base and arguments point here
  char *base;
  char **arguments; 
  int argCount;
};

struct Command parseCommand(char *cmdLine)
{
  char *cmdArgs[MAXARGS];
  struct Command cmd;
  cmd.cmdLine = strdup(cmdLine); 
  cmd.base = strtok(cmd.cmdLine, " ");
  cmd.argCount = 0;
  for (char *arg = strtok(NULL, " "); arg; arg = strtok(NULL, " "))
    cmdArgs[cmd.argCount++] = arg;
  cmd.arguments = malloc(cmd.argCount * sizeof *cmd.arguments);
  memcpy(cmd.arguments, cmdArgs, cmd.argCount * sizeof *cmd.arguments);
  return cmd;
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
  char buf[MAXIN];
  printf("Welcome to MASH!\nmash-1>");
  fgets(buf, MAXIN, stdin);
  struct Command cmd = parseCommand(buf);
  printf("Command (%d args): %s", cmd.argCount, cmd.base);
  for (int i = 0; i < cmd.argCount; ++i) printf(" %s", cmd.arguments[i]);
  printf("\n");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! this works perfectly. Sorry I didn't post full code as I should have.